# Auto generate and populate worksheets from Master

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet, auto-populate

I am looking to split data from my master worksheet but retain said data on the same excel book. I need a new worksheet created based on a range of cells i.e. C2:C19 from master (I have been able to do this using the following code).

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("C2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

For each new worksheet that is created I would like the headings and all data within the relevant row on Master pasted onto the new worksheet. i.e C2 = 10, Worksheet name 10 with headers A1 - Q1 from Master and all data from A2 - Q2 I then need each additional worksheet to do the same based on the C detail

I am very new to VBA and will be looking to take some training, in the meantime please help.

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Have you thought of copying the Master sheet instead of adding new sheets? That way, the data will already be there?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set startsheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set MyRange = startsheet.Range("C2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Set newsheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    startsheet.Rows(1).Copy newsheet.Range("a1")
    MyCell.EntireRow.Copy newsheet.Range("a2")
Next MyCell

End Sub
```